# How to search a csv file for ip addresses using a regex?

Tags: python, regex, csv, typeerror

Think I am doing something stupid here, how can I search a file for ip addresses in python using regex?

So far this is what I have:

```
def ip():
    ip = csv.reader(open('IP.csv'), delimited=',', quotechar='|')
    for x in ip:
       match = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})',x)
       if x == ipmatch:
          print(x)
```

Where am I going wrong to get `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` when I run this? Is it trying to use the match variable in the wrong place?

Comment: When your code is generating errors it's important to not only specify what it or they are, but also **where** they occur. Even better is to include the full Traceback when possible. In addition to that, providing sample input data can also be very useful to others in finding a solution for you.

Comment: Could you post some lines of example from your file?

Comment: The problem is probably because the `x` values that the `csv.reader` yields are all **lists** of values. You either need to pass each element of it to `re.findall()` separately **or** just the element that corresponds to the column in the csv file that might have an ip address in it, like `x[3]`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll remember next time I post a question! Ok so from what you are saying I can see where I am going wrong, certainly all ips that I want are in just one column. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'll see how this goes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSV file is a series of rows, each of which has multiple fields. Your `x` variable refers to each row in turn; but a row is a list, you can't use regex on a list.

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do; if you have only one field in each row you should probably not use the csv module at all, and simply iterate through the lines in the file.

Comment: I see, yes did miss out that step regarding rows and fields. All I want to do is go through the csv file and print any string from any row/field that matches the regex pattern. Seems I am going about this the wrong way